# Close Video Player Subview if video played Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I try to let my Video player close after the video is played.

```
 func playVideoPepper() {

        var maxVideoCount:Int =  5 //AnzahlderVideos
        var Random = Int(arc4random_uniform(maxVideoCount + 0))
        var VideoNumber = Random + 1


        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("pepper\(VideoNumber)", ofType:"mp4")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        if let player = moviePlayer {
            player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.scalingMode = .AspectFill
            player.controlStyle = .None
            self.view.addSubview(player.view)
            var time = player.duration
            println(time)
        }

    }
```

I tried to get the time how long one of the videos (random on of 5 videos is played) with .duration or .playableduration but both give me a 0.00 is there any easy way to let the SubView be removed if the video is played?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to subscribe to `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`, of the `MPMoviePlayerController`. This notification is posted when the player finished playing the video.

You can add the controller as an observer in the `viewWillAppear` method:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("playerDidFinish:"), name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: player)
```

Don't forget to remove the controller from the notification center this is ussualy done in `viewWillDisappear` method:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
```

See docs of MPMoviePlayerController [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMoviePlayerController)

Comment: I m really not sure how to Subscribe to the "Notificaitons" etc as this is just a small project (from a learner) for my daughter :(

Comment: Well you can subscribe to notifications using `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("playerDidFinish:"), name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: player)` this should be done in `viewWillAppear` method and you should remove the controller   `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)` in `viewWillDisappear` method

Comment: could you add this as post :)? i would love to vote it up and would be a great help for others not just have this as comment

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect what was said in that comment